# maximum with factorials

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $k>2$. Can we determine $\displaystyle \max_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac1{k10^{m!}}-\frac2{10^{(m+1)!}}$ ?
Or at least a non trivial lower bound of this maximum?

That is in relation with [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651177/transcendence-measure-for-the-canonical-liouville-number)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a link with the famous constant $0.123456789...$

Comment: It could be much easier to consider the continuous problem